# React useEffect missing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm getting a warning because my useEffect is missing dependencies, but I do not want to add these dependencies because will refresh the page every time I change the input value of these dependencies field.

I have two state data for my start and end date:

```
const [ startDate, setStartDate ] = useState(moment().subtract(3, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
const [ endDate, setEndDate ] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

As default, I load the data I'm my useEffect based on the date range:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        setDataArr(await myAPI.get({
            propertyID,
            userID,
            startDate,
            endDate,
        }));
    }
    fetchData();
}, [propertyID, userID]);
```

Then, I use them in my form. The goal is to research the data from the database based on the date range selected.

```
<Form inline>
    <FormGroup className="mb-10 mr-sm-10 mb-sm-0" inline>
        <Label for="startDate" className="mr-sm-10">Start Date:</Label>
        <DatePicker name="startDate" id="startDate" style={{maxWidth: '110px'}}
            value={startDate} onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e ? moment(e).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '')}
        />
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup className="mb-10 mr-sm-10 mb-sm-0" inline>
        <Label for="endDate" className="mr-sm-10">End Date:</Label>
        <DatePicker name="endDate" id="endDate" style={{maxWidth: '110px'}}
            value={endDate} onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e ? moment(e).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : '')}
        />
    </FormGroup>
    <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={search}>Update</Button>
</Form>
```

I'm getting the warning saying that the `startDate` and `endDate` are missing in useEffect dependency array, but if I add them, the component reload every time I change one of the date inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do:

```
const [ startDate, setStartDate ] = useState(moment().subtract(3, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
const [ endDate, setEndDate ] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
const [ dateRange, setDateRange ] = useState({startDate, endDate});

<Button
    className="btn btn-primary"
    onClick={() => {
        setDateRange({
            startDate,
            endDate,
        })
    }}
>
    Update
</Button>

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        setDataArr(await myAPI.get({
            propertyID,
            userID,
            ...dateRange
        }));
    }
    fetchData();
}, [propertyID, userID, dateRange]);
```

And now, you can set `startDate` and `endDate` without triggering the update, but it *will* update when they click *search* (since that will trigger `fetchData` when it updates `dateRange`.

Comment: Very smart solution. Thank you.

Comment: if you want to fetch data only when the user hit submit, then you can remove useEffect and just call fetch inside onClick
not sure if that is your use case or not.